# Offset origin of tiled Image in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-image, flutter-canvas

I'm trying to create a parallax background in a Flutter app, and the most efficient way to build it is to use a `Stack` with the image filling the screen as a background and then my list on top. The image is tiled with an `ImageRepeat` set on the Y axis. The plan is to then offset the origin of the tile in sync with the `ScrollController` I'm using for my list. I can then adjust the origin of the tiled image to create the parallax effect. It should be really simple. Here's some code for context:

```
Stack(
          children: [
            SizedBox.expand(
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/tiled_background_leaf.jpg'),
                repeat: ImageRepeat.repeatY,
              ),
            ),
            CustomScrollView(
              controller: _controller,
              slivers: [ ...
```

My problem is that Image does not have an `offset` property, or an `origin` position. I need some advice on the easiest way to do this. I've seen that there are custom painters, canvas methods etc, but they all seem massively over-complicated when there should be a more elegant solution within the `Image` widget, or possibly within another widget that would give me the same parallax effect.

Comment: use `Padding` as a parent of your `Image` - the docs say: *"A widget that insets its child by the given padding."*

Comment: Unfortunately, that just resizes the bounds of the Image within its parent based on the edge insets set by the padding. I need the image to fill the screen, but set the start origin of the tile to something other than 0,0.

Comment: That would produce the same results. I need a tiled repeating image across the entire screen but be able to change the origin. For example, start painting the image 100 pixels up from the top of the container but still fill the entire thing.

Comment: i see it now, `Image` has `alignment` property - by default it is 'center' - change it with `FractionalOffset` (both axis range is 0..1)

Comment: That works! Thanks. Do you want to write it up, or shall I?

Comment: Probably best to wait until I write a custom Widget that does the parallax using the offset value and a ScrollController.

Comment: great it works, feel free to post a self answer :-)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to @pskink for the answer to this (see comments above).

Here's some code for a dashboard that has a scrolling list of articles and the parallax scrolling tiled image as a background ...

```
class DashboardRoot extends StatefulWidget {
  DashboardRoot({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _DashboardRootState createState() => _DashboardRootState();
}

class _DashboardRootState extends State<DashboardRoot> {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  ScrollController _controller;

  double _offsetY = 0.0;

  _scrollListener() {
    setState(() {
      _offsetY = _controller.offset;
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      var state = Provider.of<ArticlesState>(context, listen: false);
      state.initArticleStream();
    });
    _controller = ScrollController();
    _controller.addListener(_scrollListener);
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
        bottomNavigationBar: AppBottomNavigationBar(),
        body: Stack(
          children: [
            SizedBox.expand(
              child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/tiled_background_leaf.jpg'),
                repeat: ImageRepeat.repeatY,
                alignment: FractionalOffset(0, (_offsetY / 1000) * -1),
              ),
            ),
            CustomScrollView(
              controller: _controller,
              slivers: [
                SliverAppBar(
                  elevation: 0.0,
                  floating: true,
                  expandedHeight: 120,
                  flexibleSpace: FlexibleSpaceBar(
                    title: Text(NavigationManager
                        .instance.menuItems[_currentIndex].title),
                  ),
                  actions: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.settings),
                      onPressed: () => {
                        locator<NavigationService>()
                            .navigateTo(SettingsNavigator.routeName)
                      },
                    ),
                    IconButton(
                      icon: Icon(Icons.menu),
                      onPressed: () => {RootScaffold.openDrawer(context)},
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                Consumer<ArticlesState>(
                  builder: (context, state, child) {
                    final List<Article> list = state.articles;
                    if (list == null) {
                      return SliverToBoxAdapter(
                        child: Center(
                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                              backgroundColor: Colors.amber, strokeWidth: 1),
                        ),
                      );
                    } else if (list.length > 0) {
                      return SliverGrid(
                        gridDelegate: SliverGridDelegateWithMaxCrossAxisExtent(
                          maxCrossAxisExtent: 200.0,
                          mainAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                          crossAxisSpacing: 10.0,
                          childAspectRatio: 1.0,
                        ),
                        delegate: SliverChildBuilderDelegate(
                          (BuildContext context, int index) {
                            Article article = list[index];
                            return ArticleCell(
                                article: article,
                                cellTapHandler: () {
                                  Navigator.pushNamed(
                                      context, ArticleDetail.routeName,
                                      arguments: new ArticleDetailArguments(
                                          article.docId, article.heading));
                                });
                          },
                          childCount: list.length,
                        ),
                      );
                    } else {
                      return Center(
                        child: Text("No Articles"),
                      );
                    }
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ));
  }
}
```

Notice the `Stack` has the background image inside an expanded `SizedBox` so it fills the screen space. The layer above is the `CustomScrollView` which has the `SliverGrid` and other stuff.

The important bit is the `Image`:

```
child: Image(
                image: AssetImage('assets/images/tiled_background_leaf.jpg'),
                repeat: ImageRepeat.repeatY,
                alignment: FractionalOffset(0, (_offsetY / 1000) * -1),
              ),
```

and also the property `_offsetY` which is set by the `ScrollController` listener as the users scroll:

```
double _offsetY = 0.0;

  _scrollListener() {
    setState(() {
      _offsetY = _controller.offset;
    });
  }
```

The `Image` alignment property is used to set the alignment to top, centre, left etc. but it can also be an arbitrary offset. The `FractionalOffset` value is a range `0..1` but setting it as a larger number above or below zero is also absolutely fine. Because the image is also tiled using `ImageRepeat.repeatY` the origin of the tiled image is redrawn using alignment, and by messing around with the number, you can create a nice parallax scrolling effect.

Notice that `FractionalOffset(0, (_offsetY / 1000) * -1)` has the offset value divided by 1000 (this is your speed, and the higher the value the slower the parallax of the background (think of it as the distance between the two layers). Multiplying a number by -1 switches between a positive and negative number, and changes the direction of the parallax.

Comment: btw instead of `Stack` you could use `DecoratedBox` or even ordinary `Container` together with `DecorationImage`

Comment: Thanks! I'm new to this, so still discovering all these different widgets.

Comment: I also noticed that a tiled image will always shrink to its bounds, so if the image needs to be longer than the container you have to use a Transform.scale. Also tiling doesn't work at all with transparent PNG's.

Comment: *"I also noticed that a tiled image will always shrink to its bounds"* - so i think the better option would be a custom `Decoration` class (used in `DecoratedBox` or `Container`)